# Code example racket racket/gui classes

Tags: racket

I am coming from Java and Python, and am having difficulty understanding how object-oriented code works in Racket.

1. Given

   ```
   (define food%
    (class object%
       (super-new)
       (init-field name)
       (field (edible? #t))
       (init-field healthy?)
       (init-field tasty?) ) )
   ```

   define a superclass fruit% of food% which always has the healthy? value of #t, and
   which doesn't require one to set the healthy? field when defining a new fruit.
2. In racket/gui, define a super-class of button% called text-input-button% which has two new fields, output (ideally of type text-field%) and text (ideally a string), and whose callback field has as its value a function which appends the value of the text field to the current contents of the value of the output field. Practically, the buttons would input characters into the text-field specified.

I think if I can see these two examples, a large amount of my confusion will be resolved. That being said, I am looking for the 'proper' or textbook means of doing this, rather than some round-about trick using set!, unless that is all the proper method boils down to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) Did you really mean `fruit%` should be a superclass of `food%`? It seems to me like you'd want `fruit%` to be a subclass. Here it is assuming it's a subclass:

```
(define fruit%
  (class food%
    (super-new [healthy? #t])))
```

(2) For this, I think it's best if you create a new widget based on a `panel%` to store the two sub-widgets:

```
(define text-input-button%
  (class horizontal-panel%
    (super-new)
    (init-field text)
    ;; callback for the button
    (define (callback button event)
      (define new-value (string-append (send output get-value) text))
      (send output set-value new-value))
    (define button (new button% [label "Click me"]
                                [parent this]
                                [callback callback]))
    (define output (new text-field% [label "Output"]
                                    [parent this]))))

;; testing it out
(define f (new frame% [label "Test"]))
(define tib (new text-input-button% [text "foo"] [parent f]))
(send f show #t)
```

If you really want to make it a subclass of `button%`, you could, but I think this is cleaner.

Comment: Your answer to (1) was enough to clear up the issue for me. For (2) however, I think the subclass is actually cleaner:
>    
(define text-input-button%
  (class button%
    (init-field output-text-field)
    (init-field text-value)
    (super-new
     [label text-value]
     [callback
      (λ(b e)(send (send output-text-field get-editor)
                   insert text-value))]) ))
were also correct about my intentions: I meant subclass. Your answer was very helpful: thank you very much!